# Hide app from launcher and application manager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher, android-package-managers, launching-application

I'm working on an application in which I need to hide the app from the launcher and also the application manager.

I use this code to hide the application from the launcher:

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),
PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

However, the app is still visible in the application manager. How can I hide the app from launcher and from application manager? Thus, it should not visible anywhere in the device.

Comment: What is exactly the purpose of your appication? Why do you want to hide it from application manager?

Comment: My requirment is like that. To develop an application which hides the other applications from launcher as well as an application manager.

Comment: Is it possible, kindly let me know about this.

Comment: For launcher, I know it is possible, but you need to modify the other app's manifest, which can not happen from another Android app. Overall, I think this is unfeasible.